# Find files that have recently changed

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

In Windows 8, given a specific path, how can I find all the files that have recently changed?

It used to be relatively easy in versions prior to Windows 7.

This is as close as I got:

- Open the specific path in *Windows Explorer*
- Click inside the *Search* edit-box on the top-right corner
- Open the *Search* menu that appears on the top ribbon
- Click the *Date Modified* drop-list and choose the *Today* option

This is not good enough, because I need to find all the files that have changed in the last hour or so.

After performing the sequence described above, the text `datemodified:today` appears in the edit-box. If I click it, then I can select a specific date or date-range, but this is still not good enough.

I need to specify time, so that it finds all the files that have changed between that point in time and now.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

`datemodified:‎>9/‎30/‎2014 9:30pm`

or

`datemodified:‎>9/‎30/‎2014 11:28am datemodified:‎<9/‎30/‎2014 11:30am`

More switches in the [Advanced Query Syntax article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hmmmm... That doesn't seem to work how I would expect it to, as it finds all files that have changed in the specified date **also prior** to the specified time. Thanks. BTW, the date implies that you live somewhere on the "west end" of the planet.

Comment: `datemodified:‎>9/‎30/‎2014 9:30pm` is for files modified after 9:30pm yesterday and shouldn't show files modified earlier. The second sample is for a date and time range. I think it should work with any time format or at the very least for one matching your current locale. I do believe in the 24 hour time format's superiority but I do live in Redmond, WA USA and that's how they express the time here. :)

Comment: Yep, the date on my locale is different than yours (day comes before month). I knew it, but missed it for some reason. Thanks :)